# Export function from class extending React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a React component
lets say

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    a() {
        console.log(this.props.A);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        );    
    }
```

What i want to do is expose function `a()` globally so i can access it in other parts of my application(not React) like this `window.a()`
I used to do that like this `window.a= a;` but im not sue how to do it when im accessing components props

**EDIT**

Since discussion is growing i should probably clarify what im trying to do
Im using redux togehther with react and really i want to fire redux action from GWT

so my real world code looks smth like this

```
 class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        window.fireTemplatesChanged = this.fireReduxTemplatesChanged.bind(this);

    }

    fireReduxTemplatesChanged() {
        this.props.dispatch(fechDataFromServer());
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        this.props.dispatch(fechDataFromServer());

    }

    render () {
       return (
        ...create hierarchy of components connected to redux store
       );    
    }

}




 export default connect(state => ({

    }))(Component);`
```

since this is only a part of app user is able to modify objects shown in UI of this react sreen from another places opened on top of this page

after modification is done im firing event causing redux to reload data and rerender UI accordinggly

```
       public static native void fireReactCategoryChangedEvent() /*-{
            $wnd.fireTemplatesChanged();
  }-*/;
```

Comment: Since `a` is a method of an instance of that component, you can do `window.a = instance.a.bind(instance);` once you have an instance of that component. This is probably not a good idea in general though and you should look for a better solution for whatever you are trying to accomplish through that.

Comment: @FelixKling so i asume that o good place for it would be inside constructor call ?
Alsoim aware that result wont be pretty. But im afraid that there is no pretty solutions since what im trying to do in a long term is React-GWT integration and global functions like one mentioned in questions are the only way to notify react with changes in GWT and vice versa

Comment: Inside the constructor would work, yes. Note that the function would then always refer to the last created instance.

Comment: I'll second Felix, the fact that you are trying to do this is indicative of a larger problem. Perhaps you'd be better off asking a question about how to do whatever makes you want the global in the first place.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have briefely described what is a puprose of global functions in a comment above. Hopefully one day i rewrite my whole app into react but until that time react will be living inside GWT legacy code and has to be notified about events from outside through global functions :(

Comment: Can't you just pass new props down your components when something in GWT changes? This seems preferable to exposing component internals

Comment: I have edited my questions. Ill be glad if you guys  came up  with better ideas that ive implemented since we all know that global functions are evil :)